# Multiple Salesforce Chat (embedded service) in Single-page app. How to reinitialize / destroy existing embedded service instance?

Tags: chat, angular, embedded-services

Currently in our angular app (single page app), we have one embedded service chat code in one of the pages and another embedded service chat in another page. These are two completely different chat deployments (different button/configuration/params)

The problem is when we use the first embedded chat, close it, and go to another page with different embedded chat, it doesn't create a new chat instance with the second embedded chat's configuration. It still uses the first embedded chat configuration.

Is there a way to destroy the first embedded chat instance? Or reinitialize the embedded chat upon going to the second one?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this related to Salesforce? If so, please [edit] your question to make it clearer how Salesforce is involved and be more specific about which part/feature of Salesforce you're using.

Comment: Thank you, @DerekF updated the question already

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @user3185455 can you please share some documentation on how you integrated sf live chat with embedded service in an angular application?

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! This is a Questions & Answers site, not a threaded forum. Please see the various pertinent/relevant notes in [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers), and be aware that your "answer" will likely be deleted. You can contribute in other ways to earn enough rep so that you can comment under another's post; or you could possibly ask a [new question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), and in it you can link to this question for reference if relevant.